# How to send useState value to the Parent in React

Tags: reactjs

In Parent render the list of child link *var a = [1,5,3,4]* and render child link

```
{
   a.map((item,i)=>{
      <child-component value={item} key={i} />
   })
}
```

In Child.js

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';

export function Child ({count,itemName}) {
const [number, setnumber] = useState(count);

// Send number state to parent ??

return(
    <>
        <h3>{itemName}</h3>
        <button onClick ={decrement}>decrement</button>
        <input value={number} onChange={(e)=>setnumber(e.target.value)} />
        <button onClick ={increment}>Increment</button>
        <br/>
    
    </>
)


}
```

how to send child data to the parent ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define your `const [number, setnumber] = useState(count);` in the parent Component and then props number and setNumber to child Component .....

or

if you wanna do that on advance , use combine of createContext and useReducer :)

Comment: is that possible through child data we can fetch AJAX request in parent ?? If yes kindly any code?